# How can I achieve this view of Windows Store Download List? UWP - Xaml

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am trying to achieve the following view in downloads section of my app. But I cant seem to get it right.

I also tried to Google it but came up with nothing.

[image]

I know this is `ListView` and I can use a `Grid` but then I have to create multiple `Columns` in it and give them fixed width to get a good view but it doesn't seem right because it is supposed to be an adaptive view so how fixed width will help?
And if I provide `*` as width the `Column` goes to `0` and it doesn't work as I expect it to.
I also used `RelativePanel` mixed with `StackPanel` but that only worsens the view because when I resize the window the list doesn't get resized but stays at its original size.

Any help in this regard will be appreciated.

**Update 13-Dec-2016**

Downloads.xaml

```
<ListView Grid.Row="2"
              x:Name="DownloadListView"
              ItemsSource="{x:Bind DownloadList, Mode=OneWay}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" 
                               FontWeight="Bold"
                               TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"
                               Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>

                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Type}" 
                               TextWrapping="Wrap"
                               Grid.Row="2"/>

                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                                Grid.Row="3"
                                Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
                        <TextBlock Text="MBs Received:"
                                   Width="100"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding BytesReceived}" 
                                   HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                                   />
                    </StackPanel>

                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                                Grid.Row="4"
                                Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
                        <TextBlock Text="Total MBs:"
                                   Width="100"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding TotalBytesToReceive, Mode=OneWay}" 
                                   HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <ProgressBar Value="{Binding Progress}"
                                 Height="10"
                                 Width="200"
                                 HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                 Grid.Column="0"
                                 Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                                 Grid.Row="5"/>
                    <Button Grid.Column="3"
                            Grid.Row="1"
                            Grid.RowSpan="2"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                            Background="Transparent"
                            Width="80"
                            Click="PauseResumeButton_Click"
                            Content="{Binding PauseResume, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                    <Button Grid.Column="3"
                            Grid.Row="3"
                            Grid.RowSpan="2"
                            Width="80"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                            Background="Transparent"
                            Click="CancelButton_Click"
                            Content="Cancel"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

This is only the `ListView` part of the page.
This doesn't work as the above image but it's somewhat close to it. This list view is only wide enough to put the items in it. It is not responsive as the UI changes but it's usable on mobile (I haven't checked on mobile) and pc. As it can be seen within the `XAML` design interface.

Comment: Please post the XAML you have tried.

Comment: I updated my question and it is rather temporary solution for me and I am looking to improve it though.